# "single-word-requests", "word-choice", "vocabulary" and "words" tags

Tags: discussion

We have these four tags with apparently the same purpose. That's confusing.

I think we should create tag synonyms. But what should be the master tag then?

I suggest "vocabulary". Do you agree?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think they all serve the same purpose. At least they shouldn't. Personally, I interpret these four tags as follows:

- [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) is for [word requests](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/are-word-requests-allowed/356#356), i.e. questions that ask if there's a single word that matches a given definition ([“community of experts”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/english-word-that-means-a-community-of-experts), [“obsession with publishing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/word-that-means-obsession-with-publishing), [“compliance with unspoken resistance”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/word-to-describe-compliance-with-unspoken-resistance), [“beautiful and interesting”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/read-beautiful-interesting-stories), [“device that provides constant doses of a liquid/dust/substance”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/word-for-device-that-provides-constant-doses-of-a-liquid-dust-substance), etc.)
- [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is for all those "versus" questions, where the author already has several alternatives at his disposal, but is not sure which one to use, for whatever reasons ([effect vs. affect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect), [geek vs. nerd](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4823/geek-vs-nerd), [less vs. fewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer), [jail vs. prison](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/jail-vs-prison), [“per year” vs. “per annum”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/per-year-vs-per-annum), [“I believe” vs. “I think” vs. “I reckon”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/i-believe-vs-i-think-vs-i-reckon), [plaza vs. square](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/do-plaza-and-square-have-a-different-meaning), etc.)
- [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is for more broad questions, e.g. those that ask for lots of words at once, such as [Uncommon words that should become more common](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/578/uncommon-words-that-should-become-more-common), [Terms for collections of animals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/terms-for-collections-of-animals), [Informal terms for money amounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/953/informal-terms-for-money-amounts), or "meta" questions such as [Methods for improving your spoken vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/methods-for-improving-your-spoken-vocabulary). **Edit:** fast-forward three months, and the latter question type is now actually off-topic as per the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq).
- The [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) tag, IMHO, serves no purpose beyond being an easy cop-out for new users who don't know what to tag their questions with. However, I'll admit that it is not *entirely* useless or meta, because at least it tells me that the question is not about, say, punctuation.

Of course, there are some gray areas between these definitions, not everyone will completely agree with them, and some won't know or care about the existence of all these tags to begin with. However, tag synonyms, in my book, are for tags that are completely interchangeable to everyone ([word-positioning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-positioning) and [word-order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order), [verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb) and [verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs), that kind of things). Right now, I don't see [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), and [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) being used completely interchangeably.

Comment: RegDwight, you're right, the tags don't serve exactly the same purpose. They all relate to words and vocabulary, but they are used in different situations. It's just that personally I would prefer if all tags had a broader coverage: usage, etymology, vocabulary, etc. It would then be easier for people to select the tags they are interested in. This week, for instance, I wanted to follow the tags related to vocabulary only and next week I would then move to etymology. This is still possible to do with our current tags, it is just not as easy as it could be.

Comment: Anyway, for now, this is not a big deal, as our volume of questions is still low enough to let us quickly scan them all.

Comment: Perhaps a question should be tagged with, e.g., `word-choice` *and* `vocabulary`, to cover the broader idea along with the more specific `word-choice` tag?  Too bad there is no tag hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not even sure how tags are useful on this site. It's not like I wake up one day and decide I'm only going to deal with questions about adjectives, or word-choices, or something.

Comment: @Martha: some people like grammar questions, others, perhaps vocabulary questions. in any case the site is small enough for now that you can read all new questions easily, but once it grows that might not be the case