# Credit where it is due for edits by another user

Tags: discussion, editing

A helpful user made some excellent edits to a question I posted on ELU.

How do I go about directly thanking the user for transforming an admittedly poorly formed question into topic of a great deal of discussion?

I have also accrued what I think are "unearned" reputation points for the question.  Is there a way to assign those points to the learned editor?

Thank You.

Comment: Everyone who sticks around this site for a while receives plenty of undeserved upvotes, as well as an occasional undeserved downvote. My advice is to try to avoid taking the whole reputation points system too seriously. And thanking your editor here on Meta is probably the best way to have expressed your appreciation, too—although next time you might instead leave a comment temporarily under your question on the main site.

Comment: Honestly? What @SvenYargs said: don't worry about the points, and, more emphatically than Sven, feel free to thank the editor in a comment if the edit was substantial (it's done often enough), and then remove it in a couple of days, or if you see an "upvote/agree) on your comment (like the one in front of Sven's comment above.)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the thoughtful responses this question elicited.  I'm not a "point-grubber" and mostly wanted to observe the ettiquete of the site.  The moderators' attention to these details is a Quality Assurance measure that keeps the site credible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this sounds quite strange, but here on Stack Exchange (S.E.), people *generally prefer* if you do not thank them. Evidence of this can be found in the [commentary guidelines of the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) which discourage compliments, and more concretely the network's meta thread *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)* They consider it a distracting chatter which detracts from [one of the stated purposes of the website in the tour.](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. *There's no chit-chat.* [emphasis my own]

You can read some more of the details regarding why S.E. is not considered a discussion forum in [Are Stack Exchange Sites Forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums). However, obviously, *nobody can speak for everybody*, and perhaps you have reason to believe a certain user would appreciate a personalized thank you. This is more likely to be the case, since the thank you taglines are disliked in large part because they are impersonal.

In that case, [you might be able to contact specific users in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users), if they have participated in it before. This is the most appropriate option you have on this website, because [chat is meant to be a more social (albeit "still roughly on-topic") environment than the rest of the website.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) However, please do exercise discretion while doing this, because the website is intentionally designed not to have a personal messaging system.

Some users may also include alternative contact information, e.g. an email address, on their profile if they are especially receptive towards receiving messages from other users that you might be able to use for writing a thank you letter, or whatever else you may want to communicate with them. You can check to see if that is the case by clicking on the link which attributes the post to their username. I do not believe there is a specific field for this, but it may be included in the *About Me* section of the page.

Also, all editors are accredited with their edits in the editing revision history found on the bottom center of posts.

Comment: Last poing alone merits +1, so +2.

Answer (score 3):

Editors don't expect any acknowledgement for their work from the post owners. Also, unless you have something specific to point out, there is no need to contact the editor, let alone say "thanks".

If you need to point out something specific, say, you think some edit was not to your liking, or you have some question to ask, you can add a comment under your own post and tag the editor's name in the comment. You won't see the automatic suggestion of username when you start writing an `@username` always, but the editor will be notified regardless.

Comment: I think it's polite to aknowledge the work done by an editor if it is substantial and results in a bunch of new upvotes. Nothing wrong with a comment to that effect (please don't tell me SE policy; few actually follow it, or there would be a 99% decrease in the number of comments.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I understand that. I do that myself, although never actually on my own posts (because nobody edits mine, unfortunately(?)).

Comment: @anongoodnurse Personally, I welcome feedback regarding my edits, if (and how) they were helpful or not, etc. Example: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/is-the-vocabulary-tag-helpful#comment36707_9391 But, a mere, "thanks", is still unnecessary.

Comment: Yep. We're all human.

Comment: @anongoodnurse So people say. I'm starting to think, I may be a brain in a vat. ;)

Comment: If nobody edits your posts, it may be because *it's impertinent to edit the post of a senior editor* and users know it @NVZ!