# Tag review: [meaning-in-context]

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

[meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) has roughly 250 questions. Some of these questions are good; some not as good. Today I saw a question I thought was skirting the danger line and noticed it *only* had the tag [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) and I paused to wonder about the tag.

I don't have much to say on the subject other than, "I don't know what to think yet." This topic has come up a few times in chat and the responses seem mixed. So, in an effort to foster some good discussion, what are your thoughts on this tag and its questions?

- What are the best examples from this tag?
- What are some bad examples from this tag?
- What can we do to improve questions with this tag?

> Note: I personally really like the idea of doing these styles of "tag reviews" much like we just indirectly did for [single-word-requests](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests). To be clear, I am not proposing *any* specific action regarding questions tagged [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) or the tag itself. This is meant as a good place to offer thoughts and potential advice for people who care about the tag.