# Please migrate my (closed) question to Writers.SE

Tags: support, status-declined, closed-questions, migration

My question, [Word (or shorter phrase for) "evaluate the relationship between"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76994/10942), was closed as "off topic" for this site. I think that it is a good question — it has five upvotes and seven answers — that would be on-topic at writers.stackexchange as a [properly scoped and framed critique request](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

I flagged the question to request migration five days ago, and the flag was voted helpful, but the question was not moved. Is there a reason not to move it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think its safe to say your question will not be migrated.

Comment: @simchona that is okay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a mod at Writers.SE.

Requests for words and phrases used to be on topic here on EL&U; I'm not certain what the precise current status is on these, but [Against single word requests](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests) and [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) express the problematic nature of these questions, and (this is my impression on skimming these topics...) at very least, they demand a high level of research and detail of such questions on EL&U.

Writers.SE doesn't accept such questions and never has. (We have, in the past, accepted "please critique this piece of writing" questions, which is not entirely dissimilar; however, these have been taken pretty much off-topic, for much the same reason as phrase requests on EL&U.)

If rephrased as a typographical question, e.g. *My table of contents looks awkward due to long, repeated phrase in many headers*, I think Writers could take this. This isn't "what's a shorter phrase for ," it's "I'm having a problem with my table of contents" — which is (A) a solvable, answerable problem, and (B) a problem other people probably also encounter. That'd take a fair bit of work, though, and it would invalidate a whole bunch of the existing answers. If you'd like more input, you might open a new question at Writers.SE instead of trying to migrate this one.

Minor point — As for the flag, a flag can be helpful without necessarily dictating action. Your flag raised a valid concern; it wasn't unhelpful; it didn't need to be rejected. It just also wasn't persuasive enough to spur anybody to action — or maybe their response was to check with us at Writers, and we turned the question down.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a good for Writers.SE, sorry.

One of the requirements for a critique request on Writers is that it be more than a few sentences long; questions looking to rephrase a sentence or three are considered explicitly off-topic, by community consensus. For more information on this, see this question on our meta: [Are requests for rephrasing on topic?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic)

However, I have [brought up the issue in our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5706456#5706456), in the event my opinion is not representative of the community.

One of the problems with questions like this is that there's really no way of voting on the answer. <strike>A Writers.SE critique request requires that the critique request have specific questions about the excerpt, and answers can be voted on based on their thoroughness — i.e., how well the critique addresses the author's specific questions.</strike> Requests for the rephrasing of a few sentences are much more difficult to address in this manner.

Edit: [Critique requests are now off-topic at Writers.](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/26)