# Question marked duplicate when it isn't (in my opinion)

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438913/term-for-describing-what-you-like-using-particular-adjectives) with very specific examples of people describing what they like using redundant adjectives (specifically things like *"I like well-written books"* or *"I like tasty food"*). I'm looking for a term to describe that type of statement.

This was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184857/is-there-a-word-for-a-comment-which-makes-no-sense-or-adds-nothing-to-the-curren) about comments in a discussion which add nothing to said discussion. That question is different from my question (mine is a lot more specific, and I'm looking for a more fitting term).

The duplicate was marked by a single user, without even adding a comment indicating how I would find an answer to my question in the alleged duplicate.

I'd like to hear from other users if they think my question is indeed a duplicate or if the decision to mark it as such was erroneous.

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Comment: It seems like a duplicate to me, and also a vague question that conforms to the imprecation against writing requests and crossword puzzles.

Comment: The linked post was written waaay back in 2011, as you can see SWRs are still around.

Comment: @Mari-LouA SWRs are counter to the remit of our site. The word-puzzle site has not been Area51’d yet. Unfortunately.

Comment: You gave the system about an hour to work before posting on meta. That's not enough time for anything to happen (a few reopen votes have accumulated, but not enough). Editing to add why your question is different (e.g. by listing the words suggested on the other question and why they don't work for you) and waiting a little would probably have been enough to get it reopened without coming to meta. (Even now, editing to add why those words wouldn't work would be good.)

Comment: @tchrist if you could explain why "non sequitur" or "boondoggle" which were both suggested in the accepted answer, actually fit in this case, you might help convince me that JJJ's question is a duplicate. Might. I've never heard of bland, stereotypical sentences beeing called "boondoggle" before.

Comment: The question below, without a shadow of a doubt, should be closed as a duplicate [What is a word that describes a random word presented in a conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391789/what-is-a-word-that-describes-a-random-word-presented-in-a-conversation?noredirect=1&lq=1) It also lacks any effort and... the one user who posted an answer, suggested "non sequitur"!

Comment: In the quest for fairness, I believe JJJ's question is really a duplicate of [Using an adjective to describe something that is already intended](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101830/using-an-adjective-to-describe-something-that-is-already-intended) I would suggest that JJJ edit their question and argue why the answers "redundant" and "pleonasm" are unsatisfactory.

Comment: I voted to reopen and wish I could reverse, as on second thought this question is a duplicate but sounds different to the OP because the examples are poor and inadequately researched.

Comment: I am in the same situation, and my question is nowhere near a duplicate. I edited and explained, directly quoting the other question, and still my question only needs 1 more vote to be deleted! Here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438920/i-was-late-and-so-i-got-fired-can-we-use-two-conjunctions-in-a-row

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "The linked post was written waaay back in 2011, as you can see SWRs are still around."  Please explain.  I can't find anything in Meta about this, or in the tag guidance.

Comment: @tchrist - Ditto.

Comment: @aparente001 I was commenting on tchrist's link *that* post was [written in 2011](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity), some users seemed heartily fed up with SWRs ~ *I'm now of the opinion that single word requests should be either disallowed entirely or subject to much more stringent requirements* ~  7 years later SWRs are still here. That post IMO is a bit of a dinosaur. I'm of the impression that the number of SWRs is lower today than in the past.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for explaining.  I thought maybe I had missed a development.